# Minimal set that have at least one element in n sets

Tags: algorithm

I'm solving an algorithmic problem and managed to decompose it.
Here is the sub problem I have:

I have n sets, let's say `{1,2},{2,3},{3,4}` I need to find the smallest set that have at least one element in every of these n sets, the solution here is: `{2,3}`.

It's not a greedy problem, think about `{1},{1,3},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{2,3},{2}` the solution is `{1,2}` even though `3` have the biggest frequency.

Maybe there is also a common name for that algorithm, I tried to search but didn't manage to find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the [minimum vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Computational_problem), which is NP-complete.

Let each of the values be a vertex and two vertices are adjacent if they coexist in the same set somewhere. By this construction, any element in any set will be at most distance 1 away from a cover vertex, therefore a minimum vertex cover will cover the sets. Another way to think about it, if a set does not contain a cover vertex, then there must be at least one edge in the set that doesn't include a cover vertex by construction. This contradicts the cover property, however, therefore every set will contain a cover vertex.